# Best design pattern to manage REST/JSON backend without embers data

Tags: ember.js

I need to design a "production" Ember.js app.
If I'm correct, ember data is still not ready for production.

I need to know what it the best practice to manage the JSON backend
I'm quite lost with the multitude of approaches that could be used with Ember.

Suppose I need to manage a list of Posts objects.

What I plan to do:

- Create a App.PostStore (extending Ember.object)
- Use this App.PostStore object in a App.PostsController (extending Ember.ArrayController)
- The PostsController model is a binding to the App.PostStore.all() method
- The PostController deleteMethod is calling the App.PostStore.delete(post) method

What I have see in other web site:
- Create a App.Post object
- Reopen the App.Post object adding all() method
- The PostsController model is a function calling the App.Post.all() function

Can someone share is best practices for this basic use case ?

Comment: do you want to have an object store or is simple ajax enough?

Comment: I'm open for the solution but i would like a sime mechanism to easily update the table view when successfully update the server side after an add/delete operation